# How do I autostart devilspie under gnome3 on fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, terminal, gnome3, devilspie

I am attempting to embed a gnome-terminal on my desktop using devilspie.

Adding a devilspie.desktop file in the ~/.config/autostart directory does nothing.  It does not execute on login.  However, gnome-terminal does.

Answer (score 2):

Put scriptname.desktop containing this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name="devilspie"
GenericName="devilspie"
Comment="is this necesery?"
Exec=/usr/bin/devilspie
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Gnome-Autostart=true
```

here:

/home/user/.config/autostart

Answer (score 0):

4 years has passed, and I don't know whether you have solved it.
Today I make devilspie autostart successfully.

1. Add a `.desktop` file
2. chmod +x this file

Did you do the second step?

My config is as follows(OS is archlinux):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=devilspie
Exec=devilspie
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Hidden=false
X-Gnome-Autostart=true
```